# GitHub Actions: How to conditionally set input variable of an action?

Tags: github-actions

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75904266/11065874) I learned, how to set the variable B to 1 if the `env.BRANCH_NAME` is 'f1', otherwise set it to 2.

```yaml
name: ****

on:
  push:

env:
  BRANCH_NAME: ${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }}

jobs:
  job1:
    name: *****
    runs-on: *****

    steps:
      - name: *****
        uses: some-action@some-version
        with:
          A: 1
          B: ${{ env.BRANCH_NAME == 'f1' && 1 || 2 }}  # <-- I need a change here
```

I want to change the condition such that the variable is set to 1 if `env.BRANCH_NAME` is either of 'f1' or 'f2', otherwise it is set to 2.

In Python, I would do `env.BRANCH in ['f1', 'f2']`.

How should it be done here?

Comment: See [`contains`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#contains) function.

Comment: Example: `B: ${{ contains(fromJSON('["f1", "f2"]'), env.BRANCH_NAME) && 1 || 2 }}`

Comment: what if I wanted to do `if env.BRANCH_NAME is f1 then B is 1, if f2 then B is 2, else B is 3 ` how would I do this?

Comment: For that, you can use logical grouping with`()` [operator](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#operators) and create complex expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`contains`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#contains) function along with [`fromJSON`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#fromjson) like this:

```yaml
B: ${{ contains(fromJSON('["f1", "f2"]'), env.BRANCH_NAME) && 1 || 2 }}
```

Comment: seems like it does not work if I need `B: ${{ contains(fromJSON('["f1", "f2"]'), env.BRANCH_NAME) && '' || 2 }}`. right?

Comment: @AminBa: Why not? Any error/issue? See a similar example here: https://github.com/iamazeem/security-headers-action/blob/8254020bbb97a8e1b7bf4e6fc7e1e0a35739508d/action.yml#L61

Comment: I dont know. in both cases it is returning `2`. your example is different. your example first is `2` then `''`. decided to use instead `${{ fromJSON('[2, ""]')[contains(fromJson('["f1", "f2"]'), env.BRANCH_NAME)] }}`

Comment: @AminBa: I have used it in reverse order too. Never had an issue. An [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean) would be helpful to identify the exact issue in a new question.

Comment: will work on MVCE (nice abbreviation I just learned) and will share