# How to reference matrix info with github action inputs?

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to reference a GitHub action input value in conditional, and want to also refer to the matrix data like this:

`if: ${{github.events.inputs.${{matrix.deploy_id}} == 'true'}}`
After this only, the run will be done based on above condition

Input:

```
 coachRetail:
        type: boolean
        description: Coach Retal US/Canada
```

Matrix:

```
project: Coach
            site_id: ABC
            deploy_token_name: some_deploy_token
            deploy_id: coachRetail
```

Is this the correct way to do this? Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not supported. However, you can do some manipulation in intermediate steps. Check this similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76125768/github-actions-conditionally-set-variable) as an example.