# Conditionally add values to matrix based on boolean inputs in Github Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to create a workflow that takes in some inputs, boolean, and uses them to deploy to specific sites using deploy tokens for that particular site.

Now, I have the following sample inputs and matrix defined:

**Inputs**

```
ABC:
    type: boolean
    description: ABC
XYZ:
    type: boolean
    description: XYZ
```

**Matrix**:

```
- project: ABC
     site_id: abc
     deploy_token_name: deploy_token_abc
     deploy_id: abc
- project: XYZ
     site_id: xyz
     deploy_token_name: deploy_token_xyz
     deploy_id: xyz
```

I want to add only those values into the matrix that are selected in the inputs in the workflow_dispatch.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please include in your question what you've tried so far. Thanks!

Comment: I tried using direct reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76170597/how-to-reference-matrix-info-with-github-action-inputs

But I don't think this will work

Also, I was going through this approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65384420/how-do-i-make-a-github-action-matrix-element-conditional, and got stuck with how to add multiple values in the matrix based on boolean inputs.

Comment: Read deploy_id which is defined in another file in the same folder

```
 matrix=$(jq 'map(
            . | select(${{github.events.inputs.${}}})
          )')
```

Comment: Please add a complete workflow with inputs, jobs, and steps showing the point where you're stuck or facing issues. That'll help understand your use case more clearly.